# iPhone: Problem with scope of variables

Tags: iphone, plist, scope

I have used this code to load data from a plist.

```
-(void)loadOrCreateData {
    NSLog(@"Start loadOrCreateData");
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"File Exists.. Loading from plist File");
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        font = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        background = (NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:1];
        animation = [array objectAtIndex:5];
        [array release];
        NSLog(@"Loading Done!");
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"File does not exist.. Creating new plist File");
        font = @"Georgia-BoldItalic";
        background = @"monalisa.jpeg";
        animation = @"103";
        [self saveData];
    }

    NSLog(@"Finish loadOrCreateData");
}

- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
}

- (void)saveData {
   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [array addObject:font];
   [array addObject:background];
   [array addObject:animation];
   [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
   [array release];
}
```

The first time everything loads fine when there is no plist file to get data from. But on second load, the app crashes when I try to use the loaded data outside the `loadOrCreate` method. For some reason, the data in font, background and animation is not available when accessed outside `loadOrCreate` method.  The variables -
font, background and animation are declared as NSStrings in the `.h` file and therefore should be globally available right? Can you please tell me what the reason for this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retain that objects.

```
    font = [[array objectAtIndex:0] retain];
    background = (NSString *)[[array objectAtIndex:1] retain];
    animation = [[array objectAtIndex:5] retain];
...
    font = [@"Georgia-BoldItalic" retain];
    background = [@"monalisa.jpeg" retain];
    animation = [@"103" retain];
```

Note: if you're loading data several times, then don't forget to release values before you set them.

Edit:

```
-(void)loadOrCreateData {
    [font release];
    [background release];
    [animation release];

    NSLog(@"Start loadOrCreateData");
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"File Exists.. Loading from plist File");
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        font = [[array objectAtIndex:0] retain];
        background = (NSString *)[[array objectAtIndex:1] retain];
        animation = [[array objectAtIndex:5] retain];
        [array release];
        NSLog(@"Loading Done!");
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"File does not exist.. Creating new plist File");
        font = [@"Georgia-BoldItalic" retain];
        background = [@"monalisa.jpeg" retain];
        animation = [@"103" retain];
        [self saveData];
    }

    NSLog(@"Finish loadOrCreateData");
}
```

Comment: If font, background, animation are ivars, then you have to release them in dealloc (like you wrote). Do not release them if they are static global variables.

Comment: Thanks it works. But why is it that I have to do this? Sorry, Im new to iphone app development.

Comment: In the first case (when you're getting values from array) you release array after assignment. When you release array it also releases it's objects. So you have to retain them. In the second case objects are autoreleased.